# Convergence in distribution of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}X_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

There will be $\{X_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ independent radom variables such that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}Var(X_j)<\infty$

proof that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}X_j$ converge in distribution.

This is what I tried so far.

start with:

$\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}Var(X_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E(X_j^2)-E^2(X_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E(X_j^2) - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E^2(X_j) < $

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E(X_j) - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E^2(X_j) < \infty$

now looking at: $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E(X_j) - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E^2(X_j) < \infty$ we can add $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E^2(X_j)$ on both sides and get $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E(X_j) < \infty$ (I hope that what I did is valid)

How should I continue from here?

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Let $X_n$ be the constant random variable $n$. Then $\sum var (X_n)=0$ and $\sum X_n$ is divergent. Also $X_n$'s are independent.

However if $EX_n=0$ for all $n$ then the conclusion holds: $E( \sum\limits_{k=m}^{n} X_k)^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n} EX_k^{2} \to 0$ so the partial sums of the series $\sum X_k$ converge in mean square. This implies convergence in probability and certainly convergence in distribution.

Comment: what did you refer to by writing "this"? In addition, is there possibility to prove that w/o the assumption of $E(X_j) = 0 \; for \; all \; j$

Comment: Without the assumption that the means are zero you cannot prove convergence of the series . I have given a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

look at page 112 of Probability with Maringales,DAVID WILLIAMS, it should help u.
in this page there is a prove of the question but with the assume that the expectation of each RV is 0.

Comment: I thought of this approach, but I don't know if I'm allowed to make this assumption. I there any other way to prove it w/o this assumption?

Comment: well, you can look at the RVs that are Xi-E(Xi). the VAR does not change, but u still need to show that ∑j=1∞E(Xj)<∞ converges. IDK how to do it...sorry

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.